# update the properties of an object from properties on a new one, but only if those ones on the new one aren't undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, coffeescript

Anyone know a good way to update the properties of an object from properties on a new one, but only if those ones on the new one aren't undefined?
I could do this (coffeescript):

```
setProfileData = (data) ->
      _profile.talent_id = if data.id then data.id else _profile.talent_id

      _profile.is_talent = if data.is_talent then data.is_talent else _profile.is_talent

      _profile.is_employer = if data.is_employer then data.is_employer else _profile.is_employer
```

But it seems a little longwinded.

Also the `data` is actually a class (a function), so _.extend isn't really an option.

Comment: Why would `extend` not work on function objects?

Comment: You could use `if data.id then _profile.talent_id = data.id` or `_profile.talent_id = data.id || _profile.talent_id`, but I don't think there's a coffeescript operator that avoids both duplications.

Comment: Oh actually it does, I'm using lodash and so `_.assign` works!

Comment: Oh thanks @Bergi that's also good I think I'll use that

Comment: I guess I'll make those into an answer then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JavaScript or CoffeeScript operator that does this kind of assignment. You could however avoid at least one duplication through

```
if data.id then _profile.talent_id = data.id
```

or

```
_profile.talent_id = data.id || _profile.talent_id
```

You might also use the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) (which really checks for `undefined`) instead of just falsiness.

> Also the `data` is actually a class (a function), so `_.extend` isn't really an option.

`extend` works fine on function objects as well. So if you already are using underscore or lodash, you should definitely go for that.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, I've linked the `?` operator but wanted to post code that's equivalent to the one in the question. `?=` (like `||=`) unfortunately doesn't work as it tests the assigned reference for existence, not the value.

Comment: Right, `?=` would be backwards.

Answer (score 0):

it could be like this way

```
for (var key in object_from) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       object_to[key] = object_from[key];
    }
}
```

expect help you